# Create a banded gradient in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I`m trying to create a banded gradient with Photoshop, similar to the one pictured on this packaging:

[image: packaging]

Can I achieve this with a normal gradient in Photoshop or do I have to create this rectangle by rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create this by hand, or rectangle by rectangle.  One way to *somewhat* recreate this is by going to Filter > Filter Gallery > Artistic > Cutout and playing with the settings in there.  I got this, really quickly:

[image: gradient]

It's not the prettiest or most precise, but maybe that is because of the gradient I chose.

Another way is to change the color mode to Indexed (Image > Mode > Indexed Color) and then fiddle with those settings, but this still doesn't produce exactly what you're looking for.

[image: indexed]

That's why I think it's probably best to do it by hand.  Maybe there is a method I don't know of yet, but these are the two I've seen used for this.  Most people want to *remove* the banding, so it's hard to find resources for creating it.

Comment: I am going to suggest a variant of John Manly's method. After creating the gradient, to to Image/Adjustments/Posterize and try different Levels on the slider as you watch the posterization take its effect.

Comment: Cut out and posterization can produce similar effects, though I found the posterization didn't work as well with the orange gradient I tried it with.  It might produce better results with a different set of colors